# Recursion's big O

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

This can be a dummy question. But I wan to clarify it.~So down voters..please gear up.!! ;-) ~

```
For recursive algorithms without while or for loops
 Total computation time is O(C) 
 C is total no of procedure calls 

e.g., For factorial computation it’s O(n) 
Must repeat all n operations hence O(n)
```

Above is a note I found on a book. But I do not understand what is the difference between above O(C) and O(n). For the factorial computation too (using recursion) n is the number of procedure calls..?

Comment: Is your question about the difference between using "c" or "n" to denote a generic integer? Please give me a reason not to down vote : )

Comment: Ahaa... yes u can down vote it.. Just now only got it.. I had totally missed the "e.g" phrase.. So O(n) here is just an example for O(C). I wanna delete this dumb question. :D

Comment: Don't worry, it happens... By the way, the down vote is not mine ; )

Answer (score 1):

In this citation, `C` probably means constant. In any piece of code with no `for/while loops` (or branching), there is a constant number of procedure calls. So, `O(C)` is similar to `O(1)`. 
For a factorial computation recursive code, factorial(n) is computed in `n repetitions` of the function. eg. A typical recursive code for factorial is:

```
fact(n){ 
    if(n==1 || n==0)
        return 1;
    return n*fact(n-1);
}
```

So, it takes `n repetitions` and **no for/while**. So, its complexity will be O(n).

Comment: in o(c) if c is constant, can it be a recursive algorithm? Procedure calls would be made upto a number of times until the recursion condition fails.
I think this fact is true far also the factorial one.

Comment: May be...but it can be an interpretation. Or else, what can `procedure calls` mean?

Comment: ??in o(c) if c is constant, can it be a recursive algorithm?

Comment: Don't you think the above algo for factorial, in every "visit" of function (n times), always executes 2 statements (which is a constant). Now read my answer once again, it will make some sense.

Answer (score 1):

The text only says, that recursive algorithms, where *one* call runs in `O(1)` (no loops depending on the input length or something like that), have an over all complexity of `O(C)`, where `C` is the total number of recursive calls.

This means, that you have to count the calls to calculate the complexity of such an algorithm.

E.g.

```
factorial(n)
   if n <= 1 then 
      return 1;
   else
      return n * factorial(n-1)
```

This has `n` recursive calls, so it runs in `O(n)`.

```
fib(n)
   if n <= 2 then 
      return 1;
   else
      return fib(n-1) + fib(n-2);
```

This has between `2n/2` and `2n` recursive calls and so it runs in `O(2n)`.